# Copying a class instance to another with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-object

I have a function which returns an object of class Person, defined as:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id=None
        self.age=0
        self.name=None

    def setValues(self,id,age,name):
        self.id=id_
        self.age=age_
        self.name=name_
```

And here is a function which returns such an object:

```
def getTeacher():
    pr = Person()
    pr.setValues(11,"John",30)
    return pr
```

Now, I want to assign the object returned by this function to another object in main:

```
teacher=getTeacher()
```

But it turns out teacher is a null object.
Please help

Comment: `getTeacher()` requires two parameters. You call it with no parameters. That must have caused a runtime error. If you did not have an error, then the code that you show is not the code that you executed. Please kindly update your question.

Comment: Is get teacher existing inside some class? or is it meant to be just a function. getTeacher takes two inputs (ore one if its a class method), yet in your code you pass none. so this will give a type error. Please make a minimum runable code example

Comment: Okay I have changed. Still the issue remains tho

Comment: I tested the current version of the posted code and was unable to reproduce the reported result.  It blew up in setValues because ``id_` was not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the parameters in `getTeacher` function, since the function is not inside the class Person, and id is not used in the function. You could get the teacher after this correction.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id=None
        self.age=0
        self.name=None

    def setValues(self,id_,name_,age_):
        self.id=id_
        self.age=age_
        self.name=name_

def getTeacher():
    pr = Person()
    pr.setValues(11,"John",30)
    return pr

teacher=getTeacher()
print(teacher.id)
```

Comment: Remove `self` too and move `getTeacher()` function out of the class.

Comment: hmm. It works just as expected on my end. With `teacher=getTeacher()`, you get the Person object, please try `print(teacher.age)` at the end to see whether you could access the attributes.